# How is an event based model(Node.js) more efficient than thread based model(Apache) for serving http requests?

Tags: node.js, events

In apache, we have a single thread for each incoming request. Each thread consumes a memory space. the memory spaces don't collide with each other because of which each request serves it purpose.

How does this happen in node.js as it has single thread execution. A single memory space is used by all incoming requests. Why don't the requests collide with each other. What differentiates them?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztspvPYybIY

Answer (score 0):

As you self noticed an event based model allows to share the given memory more efficiently as the overhead of reexecuting a stack again and again is minimized.

However to make an event or single threaded model non-blocking you have to get back to threads somewhere and this is where nodes "io-engine" [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) is working.

libuv supplies an API which underneath manages IO-tasks in a [thread pool](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/src/unix/threadpool.c) if an IO task is done async. Using a thread pool results in not blocking the main process however extensive javascript operations still can do (this is why there is the [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module which allows spawning multiple worker processes).

I hope this answers you question if not feel free to comment!